# Execute Python script at boot

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to execute a python script on boot, from a RaspberryPi.

I'm noticing something strange: It works, but I need to SSH into the Pi in order for it to run and work.

Ideally, I would like to be able to have it running on the Pi and that I don't have to SSH into the Pi every time I need to run it, as it is for an IoT project.

I added this line in the `/etc/profile` file in my Pi (right at the bottom):

```
sudo python /{{path}}/{{script}}.py
```

And then i gave it 755 permissions.

The bit that I don't understand is why I need to SSH in order for this to work and how can I change it so that I don't have to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, I solved this following [this guide here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/)

Main steps:

```
- create launcer.sh
- give launcher.sh 755 permissions
- sudo crontab -e
- @reboot sh /home/pi/bbt/launcher.sh >/home/pi/logs/cronlog 2>&1
- sudo reboot
```

And it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You should add "&" to the end of "sudo python /{{path}}/{{script}}.py"

```
python /{{path}}/{{script}}.py &
```

That should work as the "&" denotes that rc.local continues running even as script.py is executing also.

EDIT:: Removed "sudo" from the code, since rc.local runs as root and the "sudo" command is not required.

Comment: Thanks, i have & already, but it works only when i SSH into the PI and not if I'm not connected to it. Thanks for the suggestion about Audi, removed it.